# iOS core data corruption?

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios, ios4

This is a rather general question, as I don't have any solid evidence atm.

I have an iPhone app with about 20,000 users. It allows users to message each other, and saves those messages in core data. The only other thing it saves in core data is the users profile, a copy locally and a copy on the server.

I have a small percentage of users complaining that they receive messages but nothing shows, when they send a message (which immediately goes into core data then shows on screen) it disappears immediately. Nothing but a full restore seems to fix it, and from what I can gather, even a restore which involves them restoring a backup they just made doesn't fix it.

My first thought was that core data must have become corrupted in some way ... but the messages they attempt to send actually do send, and this would be impossible if their local profile had become corrupted too.

I've never been able to recreate it, or found anyone face to face who has had a similar problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could occur in core data that could lead to a situation like this so I can start to try and track down the problem? I'd estimate it's happening with about 1% of users.

Once again, sorry for the generality of the question, but it's all I have to work with just now!

Thanks

** Edit

Just to clarify, deleting the app and reinstalling it, does not fix the problem when this happens.

** Edit

I just had some more information from a user who is suffering from the problem ... the information my app saved in core data still exists after the app has been deleted and re-installed, all of it. I have deleted and re-installed my app hundreds of times over the last year, on countless different devices, and every time I delete and re-install, all previous data stored in core data is completely erased .. yet for these users, this is not happening. Does this sound like an iPhone issue that basically requires a restore?

** Edit 03/12/2010

AT LAST! I have some real solid information to work on. I added flurry to my latest release so I could track any core data error messages, and was able to correlate the errors received with a user id that I knew for a fact was experiencing the problem ...

The error is: "Msg: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133020.)' UserInfo=0x39c7c0 {conflictList=( 'NSMergeConflict (0x39c700) for NSManagedObject (0x38ad00) with objectID '0x375c30

Unfortunately, the error is trimmed. Flurry must have limit on the size of the message it can pass.

I don't have access to my mac and code just now, I'll start investigating as soon as I do and post back with some source code and any findings I have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a problem like that right now. So far I have figured out that the same object is modified in two NSManagedObjectContext-s. The object X has (at least) two persistent attribites, a and b, one thread changes a, another thread changes b, and CoreData cannot merge.

The key phrase in the error message is ***NSMergeConflict***:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133020.)" UserInfo=0x1544c7d0 {conflictList=(
    "**NSMergeConflict** (0xc489f40) for NSManagedObject (0xd833ca0) with objectID '0xd82b7c...

Not sure this really helps, but at least it tells you what might go wrong...

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any suggestions on what could occur in core data that could lead to a situation like this so I can start to try and track down the problem?

About a zillion different things.

Your real problem is that you are trying to debug in a speculative fashion. *To properly fix this bug, you first need to know how to reproduce the bug.* There's no other way to know if you've fixed it after you've tried something.

I would not start by blaming the underlying frameworks like Core Data. Odds are your program is the one losing the data. Start with that assumption.

Comment: "My first thought was that core data must have become corrupted in some way ... but the messages they attempt to send actually do send, and this would be impossible if their local profile had become corrupted too." ... I'm not trying to blame the underlying frameworks. What I'm hoping for is some kind of suggestion as to what can lead to my data in core data being screwed up, for example, if my code is accessing core data and the battery dies, would it handle it? If I know of any vulnerabilities in core data that commonly lead to problems, then I can try to reproduce the error and fix it

Comment: @Steven It's next to impossible to help you solve your problem. Your first step must always be to figure out how to reproduce a bug before it can be fixed. All the speculation in the world will probably be a waste of time.

Comment: I agree that speculation is not the greatest place to start, but sometimes it's all you've got to go on! I have been able to track down some more information from a helpful user, I'm editing the above question to include it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does it affect these users from the moment they set up there account?  Could it be something to do with their username/id/personal information?

If deleting the app completely and reinstalling doesn't solve the problem, then I'm at a loss for how it could be core data - as you yourself say, I often do this and it removes all core data each time.  So if it is core data corruption, it would have to be in your construction of the core data instead of the database itself.  I don't think it likely that only people who install your app would have problems with core-data being retained.

If you have contact with a user experiencing this problem, I would get them to try to create a new username that is "safe and normal".

Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I was away on business for a few days! No, it doesn't affect the user from the moment the create their account. They create their account and everything is fine, for weeks or even months, then all of a sudden the problem appears. The app contacts the server, downloads new messages into core data, then is unable to retrieve them from core data. Then all the other symptoms appear as described (data not being erased from core data when app is deleted etc). I've created accounts with the exact same details, and even downloaded their messages on to my device but all is ok!

Comment: Could their devices be low on memory?  Core Data files may grow in chunks - if the device didn't have enough memory for the allocation I don't know what would happen.  Sounds like it might be the culprit.  When you are testing - are you downloading their entire Core-Data db onto your device?  Or only the messages that were causing grief - might also be a limit to the size of the db.  But if it is just text I can't see that really happening.